# How to supress info message "io.bytes.per.checksum is deprecated" in grunt shell

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

When analyzing a Big Data I'm running Apache Pig version 0.17.0 on top of Hadoop-2.7.2. Every time i run a `load` command in local mode of `grunt>` shell i get the following message:

```
grunt> A = load '/usr/lib/pig/data.txt' using TextLoader as (date:chararray);
[main] INFO org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation-io.bytes.per.
checksum is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.bytes-per-checksum
```

Is there away to switch off this message as it becomes very annoying with frequent usage of `grunt>` shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if below solution works for you,

Create a file named nolog.conf, with the following content

```
log4j.rootLogger=fatal
```

and then run pig as follows

```
pig -x local -4 nolog.conf
```

Comment: Thanks Ajay! Your solution is working perfectly, not even suppressed this message but also improved the execution speed. You are the Big Data Champion!. Thanks again.